# Passando consulta no BD pelo node para Array em Javascript Front-end

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

Olá, recentemente estou estudando uma pouco de programação web (sou bem inciante) e acabei caindo em node.js, estou achando tudo incrível só estou com um certo problema, quero acessar o mysql retornar uma consulta pelo node e passar esse JSON para um array no javascript dentro do ejs (html) front-end, porem não estou conseguindo, o que estou fazendo de errado? Segue o código de acesso ao BD (obs a conexão com o banco está funcionando então não vou inseri-la aqui)

```
connection.query('select * from marcadores', function(err, results){
    res.render('map',{lista : results});
});
```

e Segue o código dentro do javascript (front)

```
var locations = Array();
    <%for(i = 0; i<lista.lenght;i++){%>
        locations.push(<%lista[i].id%>);
        locations.push(<%lista[i].titulo%>);
        locations.push(<%lista[i].latitude%>);
        locations.push(<%lista[i].longitude%>);
```

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo de como queres que o HTML saia?

Comment: Esta aplicação que estou testando é com Google Maps, a ideia é passar as informações do vetor para um objeto dentro do Objeto Map e exibir depois

Comment: Então queres passar `{lista : results}` para uma variável em JavaScript, é isso?

Comment: Isso, não sei como passar da consulta do banco (node.js) para o javascript que esta no meu arquivo html

Comment: A minha resposta ajudou?

Answer (score -1):

Nesse caso podes usar assim:

```
<script>
var objeto = JSON.parse('<%-JSON.stringify(lista)%>');
</script>
```

Desse modo o objeto que é passado ao EJS é passado ao HTML dentro da tag script e o JavaScript vai encontrar uma string lá e faz `JSON.parse` dela tornando-a num objeto de novo.